# Copy path in CodeAcademy

Tags: html

I am a beginner at HTML I am trying to put one of my projects on to a workspace on CodeAcademy.

I however have multiple html files that I have uploaded.

The intended code should work such that if I press the "whatever" button, it takes me to that page using directory of that file.

I have gotten this to work locally on my personal laptop because I know the directory (ex: C:/user)

Now that I have uploaded it to the CodeAcademy workspace, I do not know hot to get a certain files source.

Any help would be appreciated. (I am assuming only someone who has used CodeAcademy workspace might be familiar with this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use relative path instead...

Let's say your project structure is like this:

```
pages/about.html
services.html
index.html
```

**In index.html:**

```
<a href="./index.html">Home</a>
<a href="./services.html">Services</a>
<a href="./pages/about.html">About</a>
```

**In services.html:**

```
<a href="./index.html">Home</a>
<a href="./services.html">Services</a>
<a href="./pages/about.html">About</a>
```

**In pages/about.html:**

```
<a href="../index.html">Home</a>
<a href="../services.html">Services</a>
<a href="./about.html">About</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using relative paths rather than absolute paths?

For example, instead of `C:\Users\Vivek\Desktop\hello.html`, simply `hello.html`